# Applet using JNLP: messages in Java console

Tags: java, applet, jnlp, next-generation-plugin

I am displaying applet using JNLP. I have written all the necessary files. The jars are signed. Even applet is loading fine. I am getting lots of messages in Java console which are contributing to delay in applet loading.

```
basic: JNLP2ClassLoader.findClass: pack.XMLDropDown$1: try again ..
basic: JNLP2ClassLoader.findClass: pack.XMLDropDown$2: try again ..
basic: JNLP2ClassLoader.findClass: pack.XMLDropDown$3: try again ..
basic: JNLP2ClassLoader.findClass: pack.XMLDropDown$4: try again ..
basic: JNLP2ClassLoader.findClass: pack.XMLComboBoxModel: try again ..
basic: JNLP2ClassLoader.findClass: pack.XMLToolTipManager: try ..
...so on.
```

Lots of messages in Java console.

PS. Applet is working fine. Just wanted to know the cause for ***try again*** messages.

Answer (score 3):

It's worth noting that although initially confusing, this trace logging can be useful.

To interpret the output:

- If you see a class mentioned once, that is expected, and the try again part didn't happen, because it was loaded on the first attempt
- If a class is listed on two consecutive lines, that means it was unable to be loaded and the thread of execution has been killed (your class may stop executing half way through a method)

This output could be much clearer, but having recently hit this issue, I'm glad at least something was printed

Answer (score 2):

Try unchecking "Enable tracing" in your Java Preferences (Advanced -> Debugging -> Enable Tracing). That worked for me. On Mac, there's an app to set Java Preferences in your Utilities folder (Applications -> Utilities).

Comment: In fact the problem is that it pollutes traces when you actually need to read them

Comment: Yeah, good point. I don't know how to only eliminate the "try again..." statements.